# Get Mac-Address of Host from within Docker Container

Tags: linux, docker, docker-network

In my dockerized application I need to have a hardware anchor and thought about using the Container's Mac-Address. But: since the Mac-Address of a Docker container ist volatile and dynamically assigned at container startup I cannot use this Mac-Address (see [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings))

> The MAC address is generated using the IP address allocated to the
>   container to avoid ARP collisions, using a range from
>   02:42:ac:11:00:00 to 02:42:ac:11:ff:ff

The Mac-Address of the Docker host would be a viable solution.

How can I access the (linux) host's Mac-Address from within a container running on this host?

Comment: I'm in the same situation as you. Did you figure out a solution apart from the below given answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the mac address to the container as an env variable when starting it

```
docker run -e mac=$(ip link show eth0 | awk '/ether/ {print $2}') alpine env
```

Comment: Ok, but that requires manual efforts during startup. Is there a solution without explicitly handing over the mac-address to a container?

Comment: What would be an equivalent docker-compose solution without ```.env``` file?

Comment: This doesn't work with Rancher and rancher-compose. So is there a solution also for Rancher environments?

Answer (score 1):

If you run in net mode "host" you can retrive the mac from the container, and wouldn't need to pass it in.