# Is there is anyway to get host Mac and ip address inside docker container using java progams

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker

I have tried below program on System it returns the host IP address but when running as docker container its give container IP

```
public static Map<String, String> getMAC(){
        Map<String, String> dataMap = new HashMap<>();
        try{
            InetAddress inetaddress=InetAddress.getLocalHost(); //Get LocalHost refrence
            String ip = inetaddress.getHostAddress();  // Get Host IP Address
            dataMap.put("ip", ip);
            //get Network interface Refrence by InetAddress Refrence
            NetworkInterface network = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(inetaddress);
            byte[] macArray = network.getHardwareAddress();  //get Harware address Array
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

            // Convert Array to String
            for (int i = 0; i < macArray.length; i++) {
                str.append(String.format("%02X%s", macArray[i], (i < macArray.length - 1) ? "-" : ""));
            }
            String macAddress=str.toString();
            dataMap.put("mac", macAddress);
            //return dataMap; //return MAc Address
        }
        catch(Exception E){
            E.printStackTrace();  //print Exception StackTrace
            //return null;
        }
        return dataMap;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#use-cases-and-workarounds), you can get the host's IP address by resolving `host.docker.internal`. So try changing the first line in the try block to:

```
InetAddress inetaddress=InetAddress.getByName("host.docker.internal");
```

> This is for development purpose and will not work in a production
> environment outside of Docker Desktop for Mac.

Comment: pls check i'm getting null now

Comment: Are you using Windows or Linux? If Windows, Docker desktop or toolbox?

Comment: has to use in Linux but for now I am testing on mac

Comment: This should work with [Docker Desktop for Mac](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#use-cases-and-workarounds). Are you using version `18.03+`?

Comment: yea its not working is there any other way to get access mac or IP of host machine not docker

Comment: is there a way to get mac as well as IP or if you have tried then pls send me that code snippet

Comment: The only solution I can think of is to pass the mac address as an environment variable to the container. Demonstrated here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48264388/7414734